# jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging

I am having trouble using jQuery to fadeOut() an image and fadeIn() another when a button is clicked.

To keep it simple, here is the HTML of just the part that needs to be affected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="landing-page">
            <div id="call-to-action">
                <img src="https://scontent-b-lga.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/v/1608452_3821343707689_2110853534_n.jpg?oh=ab5ebfd5dce574e97a43e9a7c0739583&oe=52D0F2AC" id="learn-button"/>
            </div>
            <img src="https://scontent-b-lga.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/v/1551908_3821359708089_1101636385_o.jpg?oh=aa19a9ac5f5b5e4f3cf704858482803d&oe=52D11726"id="line"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#call-to-action").click(function() {
        $("#landing-page").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#more-info").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

When the button #call-to-action is clicked, the #landing-page div should fadeOut, and the #more-info image should fadeIn. It is not working. In fact, any jQuery command I've typed in has not worked for other divs. I believe there is something wrong with my jQuery plugin, or I'm missing some reference to the jquery sheet.

Comment: I cannot see any tag with id of `more-info`. Anyway, if nothing seems to work, have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: You're right. I forgot to include the #more-info image in the posting, but it is right under it in my actual html document. How do I check the browsers console for errors?

Comment: you can check for error using FireBug

Answer (score 1):

> *"or I'm missing some reference to the jquery sheet."*

Yes. The code you show does not include the jquery.js file. If you have a copy of jquery.js in your project then add this in the `<head>` section immediately *before* your other JS include:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
```

Otherwise you can reference a copy from a CDN:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

(Specify whichever version of jquery you want to use in accordance with what your chosen CDN supports; I've suggested the latest version compatible with old IE.)

Also you probably want to hide the second img to start with, and not fade it in until the first img has finished fading - if you pass a function as the second argument to `.fadeOut()` it will be called after the fadeout finishes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#more-info").hide();
  $("#call-to-action").click(function() {
    $("#landing-page").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $("#more-info").fadeIn("slow");
    });
  });    
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/OmaCOju/1/edit

Comment: Is there a reason I missed why this answer suggest an age old version of jQuery?

Comment: @MartinAndersson - Version 1.10.2 isn't "age old", it is the _latest_ version of jQuery that is compatible with old IE (unless you count 1.11, which is still beta). v1.10.2 was released at the same time as v2.0.3...

Comment: oh my bad. I kept reading version "1.1" in my head. I was glad jQuery finally dropped support for.. AGE OLD IE:s =).

Comment: @MartinAndersson - Yes, it's good to have the option, but at my own job I have to support at least back to IE8 so that means using the latest 1.x stream of jQuery rather than 2.x.

Comment: @nnnnnn My script.js file is my jQuery file.  It was referenced right after my css reference as: <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

Comment: @user3182933 - Do you mean that you've renamed "jquery.js" to "script.js" and added your own code to the _end_ of the jquery source? (Or used some build tool to combine your scripts into a single file?) In your question you said no jQuery commands were working for you, which to me implies you haven't included jquery.js at all...

Answer (score 0):

You missed to include the jquery library. You can include it from google CDN. From you question i understand that on click of a button you want div to be fade-in and fade-out. Please refer the below demo for doing this.

Demo : http://jsbin.com/IGAJeqew/2/edit